# what is the command to extract last column if this is the input to a file using awk. How to use awk with multiple delimiters like () \t and ' '

Tags: bash, shell, awk

If this is the input to a file

```
testabc     Perf Agent data collector                        (26748)  Running
midaemon    Measurement Interface daemon                     (26565)  Running
ttd         ARM registration daemon                          (1779)   Running
alarm        Alarm generator                                 (26764)  Running
coda         Performance Core                 COREXT                Stopped
opcacta      Action Agent                    AGENT,EA     (26635)  Running
opcle        Logfile Encapsulator            AGENT,EA     (26613)  Running
opcmona      Monitor Agent                   AGENT,EA     (26620)  Running
opcmsga      Message Agent                   AGENT,EA     (26597)  Running
opcmsgi      Message Interceptor             AGENT,EA     (26641)  Running
abcdccb     Communication Broker             CORE         (26571)  Running
ovcd         Control                          CORE         (26567)  Running
ovconfd      Config and Deploy                COREXT       (26588)  Running
Message Agent is not buffering.
```

Any help is much appreciated. Only "awk" needs to be used not even nawk as it is not installed in most systems.

Answer (score 3):

try this;

```
 awk '{print $NF}' <YourFile>
```

NF: gives you the total number of fields in a record

Answer (score 0):

If you have `rev` installed, you can just use it and process the first column, then `rev` back:

```
rev < file | awk '{print $1}' | rev
```

You can also use `cut` instead of awk:

```
rev < file | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev
```

That's what I usually do, it's surprisingly fast.

Comment: rev is not installed in our systems. The idea is to write the script using the  commands already installed

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F' ' '{print $NF}'

-F - delimiter(whitespace is the default)
$NF - last column, $(NF-1), last but one column and so on
```

Comment: Thanks Anudeep. Could you help me with the command if i want to use multiple delimiters like () \t and ' ' only with awk

Comment: You can specify like

        
        awk -F '[:;/=]' '{print $0}'
        delimiters above are ":, ;, /, ="

Comment: am getting the below error while using multiple delimiters.                                   awk -F '[:;/=]' '{print $0}' test_file                                                        awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
OS is solaris.

Answer (score 0):

AWK:

```
awk '$0=$NF""' file
```

Replace the record `$0` with the last field `$NF` and print.

Comment: This will not work, if your `$NF` evaluates to numeric `0`. A common mistake that I also used to make... :-/

Comment: ... meaning it prunes out empty lines. You are right,

Comment: Not just empty lines. If your lines is something like `midaemon    Measurement Interface daemon                     (26565)  Running 0`, it will not be printed.

Comment: You are right. Fixed (changed `$0=$NF` to `$0=$NF""`).